# Modify the step-filter to only show project classes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to debug an android application I'm running to see where the problems in my code are.  All I'm trying to do at the moment is step into a method I wrote to check whether a database exists but the debugger just keeps going through code from JARs and only code I don't care about.  Right now when I try to step into the method the debugger opens a page for something called DexPathList.findClass(String).  Here's a screenshot of what it looks like when I first try and step into my method:

[image]

and the screen that pops up after I hit Step Into for DexPathList.findClass(String):
[image]

How can I skip all these superfluous bits on information and just look at my own code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way: Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left mouse</kbd> and click on the method name where you want to stop. That's called [hyperlink debugging](http://blog.deepakazad.com/2012/07/eclipse-tip-stepping-into-selection-and.html).

The long term solution is to add [step filters](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-usestepfilters.htm) which exclude those unwanted classes from the debugger.

Comment: I tried to change it using step filters and it did skip a couple of classes but I hit a wall when I got to DexPathList.findClass.  I could find any class by that name or find anything through Google about it either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug ONLY your Android project, use step filter (Windows -> preference -> java -> debug -> step filter). Here a list of package you have to filter :

[image: How to set step filters for Android]

Now you can step into without fear =)

Comment: If your package start by "com.example.*", just refactor and take off "com.".